# Proportion of explained variance for a probability model(binary logistic regression)

Tags: probability, logistic, variance

in the article written by Frank Harell ,Statistically Efficient Ways to Quantify Added Predictive Value of New Measurements,(https://www.fharrell.com/post/addvalue/)

Harell is writing:

For a probability model, the natural way to express the proportion of explained variance is through the predicted probabilities that Y=1, denoted by $(\hat{P})$. The $(R^2)$ measure for a binary Y model is then $\frac{\text{var}(\hat{P})}{\text{var}(\hat{P}) + \sum_{i}^{n} \hat{P}_{i} (1 - \hat{P}_{i}) / n}$ where $\text{var}(\hat{P})$ is the sample variance of the $(n)$ $(\hat{P}_{i})$

I cannot understand this term in the denominator: $ \sum_{i}^{n} \hat{P}_{i} (1 - \hat{P}_{i}) / n$. How do I interpret it. Is this some kind of residual variance not explained by the model?